# Opportunity coming back to Eloqua from sales does not return Campaign contribution name due to this it does not display in campaign revenue metric?

Tags: salesforce, eloqua, eloqua-bulk-api

opportunity coming back from sales to eloqua have Amount that has to display in cmpaign revenue in won attribute section but when the Opportunity does not display contributed campaign in opportunity search section under campaign tab due to this i am not able to get Close loop reporting campaign revenue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eiH1.png)

I have try with multiple campaign integration dut still it is not working , I want the hole close loop reporting like if opprtunity is coming back it should go not fist campaign that contact has responded the revenue of that opportunity should be displayed under attributed revenue under closed loop reporting section
like this image it has to display
this image that i am getting does not display anything :-[myoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8KsU.png)
[want this type of output :-expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QI7b.png)